# Numerically most robust way to compute sum of products (standard deviation) in floating-point?

Tags: algorithms, st.statistics, na.numerical-analysis

I stumbled across a paper by Welford (1962), where he proclaims a method that should compute the standard deviation numerically more robust than the naive algorithms (http://www.jstor.org/stable/1266577).
Here, "numerically robust" means that round-off errors are reduced.

He gives a recurrence for the sum of squares $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \mu_n)^2 = S_{n-1} + \frac{n-1}{n} (x_n - \mu_{n-1})^2 $ , $\mu$ being, of course, the mean.
That way, the standard deviation can be computed iteratively in a single pass.

As far as I understand, he claims that his iterative recurrence formula is numerically more robust, because all terms in it are of the same order (provided the input data are all of the same order).

This is what I don't understand. It seems to me that, as $n$ gets incremented, $S_n$ becomes larger and larger, so more and more significant digits from the second term are lost, aren't they?

Googling a bit further, I have found a paper by
Youngs & Cramer, 1971, who looked at a number of methods, including Welford's, of computing the sum of products / standard deviation more robustly (http://www.jstor.org/stable/1267176).

Conducting a number of experiments, they found that Welford's method does not provide any benefits. So that seems to confirm my doubts about Welford's method.

Now, Youngs & Cramer propose another method, which computes $S_n = S_{n-1} + \frac{n-1}{n}(nx_n - s_n)^2 $, where $s_n = s_{n-1} + x_n$.
Empirically, they found their method to be superior.

Again, I don't understand why this should be the case: isn't there some catastrophic cancellation going on in $(nx_n - s_n)$ ? Don't the terms $S_n$ and the fraction differ in their magnitude more and more, so that more and more digits of the fraction term get rounded off?

I would by most grateful if somebody could shed some light on these questions.
In addition, I'd like to know which is the best method (in terms of roundoff errors) to compute these sums. Surprisingly, I haven't found anything about this in Numerical Recipes (or I overlooked it).

Thank you very much in advance.
Gabriel.

Comment: For certain values of A and B (where B is the average), it might be helpful to compute the result as (A+B)(A-B).  Perhaps a numerical analyst can say how bright/stupid this would be in terms of minimizing roundoff error?  Gerhard "Email me About System Design" Paseman. 2011.07.14 

Comment: Re: Youngs & Cramer's critique of Welford's method: their analysis has been criticized in *Ling, R. F. (1974). Comparison of Several Algorithms for Computing Sample Means and Variances. Journal of the American Statistical Association, 69(348), 859. doi:10.2307/2286154*.

Answer (score 2):

I found a discussion of this exact problem in Higham, *Accuracy and stability of numerical algorithms*, Section 1.9.

The author suggests an alternative algorithm and claims that it is numerically stable (in the mixed backward-forward sense); proofs for the precise accuracy bounds of the formulas are left as exercises.

Comment: The book is on Google books, http://books.google.com/books?id=epilvM5MMxwC&lpg=PP1&dq=accuracy%20and%20stability%20of%20numerical%20algorithms&pg=PA11#v=onepage&q&f=false , although for some odd reason the pages have been scanned upside down.

Comment: It would help to summarize the algorithm at the link.  I don't have time to, but here is a direct link to Section 1.9, which starts on page 11: [Higman, p. 11](https://books.google.com/books?id=7J52J4GrsJkC&lpg=PR2&pg=PA11#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Answer (score 0):

For the variance (square of std), personally I would use this simple one:

(  n (sum x*x )  -  (sum x)*(sum x)  )  /  (n*n)
or:
   ( (sum x*x ) - (sum x)*(sum x) / n ) / n

[ For the case of relatively small variance ("catastrophic cancellation") check also:
http://www.daheiser.info/excel/notes/NOTE%20P.pdf ]

Edit:

A viki page also reports a nice discussion:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance#cite_note-1

In particular, it mentions:
A numerically stable algorithm is given below. It also computes the mean. 
This algorithm is due to Knuth,[1] who cites Welford.[2]
[...]
This algorithm is much less prone to loss of precision due to massive cancellation, but might not be as efficient because of the division operation inside the loop.

About the 2-pass algo, it says:
"This algorithm is often more numerically reliable than the naïve algorithm for large sets of data, although it can be worse if much of the data is very close to but not precisely equal to the mean and some are quite far away from it."

I'd say that if the variance is not small (as often happens) and ease and speed of computation are a priority, the simpler version (closer to the definition) could still be considered.

Comment: I am not an expert in numerical computation, but your simple formula has low precision when x_i’s are large and the variance is small.

Comment: I have done some problems that required iterative computation of mean/variance, and I have used this simple formula. It can have catastrophic cancellation. I used a multiprecision library (GMP) to store intermediate results at very high precision (128 bits or so) and that worked fine.


Comment: Is the above formula from Youngs & Cramer written correctly? From a quick check i am not getting the sum of squares.

Comment: For the cases rightly considered by Tsuyoshi Ito, check out also:
http://www.daheiser.info/excel/notes/NOTE%20P.pdf

Comment: David, as you are at it, what about if we use something like:
( sum (x^2 / n)  -  (sum (x / n) )^2 ) 
where the divisions are carried out before the sum (to avoid the difference between possibly similar large numbers) ?
Do you still see the same problem with small variances ?

Comment: Where you do the divisions basically doesn't matter. In general, multiplications are always numerically stable, it's the additions (more accuractely, subtractions) that are dangerous.
For example, say $n$ is a power of two. Then doing the divisions before or after only changes a few bits in the exponent. The mantissa (where the errors can occur) is literally exactly the same.


Comment: Your method can exhibit what numerical analysts call "catastrophic cancellation" because you're subtracting two terms that potentially agree to several figures. See an illustration of what could go wrong here: http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2008/09/26/comparing-three-methods-of-computing-standard-deviation/

Comment: Right, David and John, i can see that. The proposal to give a try also to the version where divisions are performed "within" the sums: ( sum (x^2 / n) - (sum (x / n) )^2 ) was motivated by the idea that, by doing so, the operands involved in the final difference would be much smaller, while, clearly, the difference: ( n (sum x^2 ) - (sum x)^2 ) would have much larger operands. So i was hoping that the "relative error" could be smaller. Was that an incorrect thought ? 

Comment: Yes, it is an incorrect thought.  Using smaller operands by a factor of n^2 simply results in a smaller result by the same factor with the smaller error by the same factor, and the relative error is the same.

Comment: I have partly modified the answer as an initial reaction to the beautiful constructive feedbacks. [ I have also replaced the x^2 with x * x to avoid that someone could actually use an exponentiation operator in the practical implementation (probably taken care by compiler, anyway). ]

Comment: @Luna: I fail to see how your method avoids the numerical problems.
And the wiki page that you mention gives exactly the algorithm that was proven ineffective by Youngs & Cramer (despite the fact that it is also cited by Knuth).

@David: yes, a multiprecision library would, of course, always work - but right now I'm just trying to understand which method for computing the variance is more stable, and *why* that is.

@John: your comparison is very interesting! It also supports what Youngs&Cramer found, i.e., that Welford's method is no more stable than the direct method.


Comment: @Gabriel, @John D. Cook, @Tsuyoshi Ito, @David Harris you are right. The simpler method clearly does not avoid the possible numerical problems. However, what i can say is that it is easy and fast, and having used it in many projects i have never seen any problem in practice. Clearly, in specialized applications where you know that the variance is going to be systematically relatively small (maybe some astronomy application, etc), you have to pick a method which avoid the "catastrophic cancellation" problem.

Comment: ... Probably, the best thing, is to proceed by experiment. It would be nice, if once you reach some conclusion you let us know (i would be personally interested).   ;-)
